# Pointwise Limits: Diagonal Sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant to record.
*(For more details see: [Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))*

For jeopardy it is written as question anyway. Have fun! :)

**Problem**

Consider the pointwise limit $f(x):=\lim_m f_m(x)$.

Mostly well-known it fails:
$$f_m(x_n)\to f_m(x)\quad(x_n\to x)\nRightarrow f(x_n)\to f(x)\quad(x_n\to x)$$
*(That is continuity is not preserved under pointwise limits.)*

Now, can it happen that diagonals fail to converge as well:
$$f_n(x_n)\nrightarrow f(x)\quad(x_n\to x)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can happen. Take $f_n(x) = x^n$ for $x \in [0,1]$, and $x_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$. Then
$$f_n(x_n) = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \to \frac{1}{e}$$
while $f(1) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can fail!

Consider the standard example by polynomials:
$$f_m:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}:f_m(x):=x^m$$
Then one attains every possibly value:
$$x_n:=\sqrt[n]{a}\quad(0<a<1):\quad f_n(x_n)\equiv a\nrightarrow1=f(1)$$